# Use Jess rules in Java: Asserted instances cannot be used for further reasoning

Tags: java, rules, protege, jess

I am using JessTab API for manipulating ontologies in Java through Jess rules. A simple ontology with a class Person is used as an example. I ran the following code from Java to assert new instance for class Person:

```
private final Rete r = new Rete();
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
r.executeCommand("(make-instance test of http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1431767500.owl#Person)");
```

A simple rule to list the individuals of class Person like follows does not show up the newly asserted instance test:

```
(defrule listPeople
    (object (is-a http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1431767500.owl#Person)              
        (OBJECT ?p)              
    ) 
=>  
    (printout t "Person instances: " (instance-name ?p) crlf)    
)
```

Doing this in Protege IDE with JessTab shows up the instance, but running from Java NetBeans does not consider the facts asserted by the make-instance command. I tried to save the ontology after executing the make-instance command and then run the rule but the same behavior appears i.e. new facts are not considered. Do I have to run a specific JessTab command?

Comment: `make-instance` isn't among the Jess functions. In any case, you should check or display the return value of `Rete.executeCommand` to learn whether it has succeeded or not. Moreover, `executeCommand` is deprecated - use `eval` instead.

Comment: Thnx @laune. From the JessTab documentation I observed that a keyword map is needed if it has to be mapped into Jess's WM. It works now. May Allah bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The make-instance command should include the map keyword:

```
r.executeCommand("(make-instance test of http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1431767500.owl#Person map)");
```